# What technology would you use for 52 inch monitor, data driven applications?

Tags: java, wpf, html

I have large HD TV's to use as monitors, and I need to show data from various sources (SQL, XML, etc) and can use a PC running Windows or Linux to drive the displays.

As for the app, I'm envisioning MSNBC- or CNN-like layouts (tickers, video in one corner, other text/data in the opposite corner, big video feed or scrolling text/graphics in center).  This needs to appear in full screen mode, and there won't be any user interaction, this is simply for display purposes.

What technologies would you use to build this app?

Comment: Seems like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004276/libraries-and-pseudocode-for-physical-dashboard-status-board/3006967) might be similar (although I didn't flag it as a duplicate).

Comment: 52" or 100" is irrelevant, resolution is the key. You can set 800 x 600 resolution for 14" monitor or 52" monitor.

Comment: @Jimmy Sawczuk - thanks, did not see that wieh searching and did not come up in the "similar" list.  Great reference point and though my question was vague, I got the answers I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built something like this using HTML5, JavaScript/jQuery, and CSS (and PHP on the backend to handle talking to the Facebook Graph API and our mySQL server). My company is built around Facebook pages and their growth, and the main area of the graph rotates through screens showing various pages and how they're growing. The left panel shows the weather, time, and a list of upcoming pages so people walking by can see if something they're interested in is coming up.

I use [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to generate the graphs that show growth, and we have a Google TV that's just sitting in Chrome on that one web page. Each screen shows up for 20 seconds, and the page automatically refreshes the entire thing periodically (every hour) to ensure it has the latest up-to-date page definitions (actual data is loaded via AJAX).

Hope that helps! (I'll see about getting a picture to give you a better idea of what's going on.)

Comment: Thanks.  Rather neat setup and right inline with my thinking.